# What are these numbers in Goto Anything of Sublime Text 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sublimetext2

I've googled a lot but unfortunately I can't find out what these numbers aside the file names means when you `Ctrl+P (Goto Anything)` in Sublime Text 2.

Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Number of occurrences of the "a" ?

Comment: I believe it is the relevance match of your search term with the file name. If you type more the number goes up.

Comment: I'd assumed it was the fuzzy match score.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to hearsay:

- Indicator of how likely your input is meant to describe that file.
- Increases with match quality. Typing in "application" in your screenshot should yield significantly higher numbers.
- Increases with the popularity of the file. As a result, it will display the busiest file first if there are multiple matches.