# Sublime Text Fuzzy file Search numbers

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I use `Goto Anything` (Cmd+P) I see some numbers at the left of the file:

[image]

What does `136` means there?

Comment: [offtopic] What color scheme you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like it has been answered in other related [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252340/what-are-these-numbers-in-goto-anything-of-sublime-text-2):

> - Indicator of how likely your input is meant to describe that file.
> - Increases with match quality. Typing in "application" in your screenshot should yield significantly higher numbers.
> - Increases with the popularity of the file. As a result, it will display the busiest file first if there are multiple matches.